# Using scrapy and xpath to parse data

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, pipeline

I have been trying to scrape some data but keep getting a blank value or None. I've tried doing next sibling and failed (I probably did it wrong). Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Website to scrape (final): https://www.unegui.mn/azhild-avna/ulan-bator/

Website to test (current, has less listings): https://www.unegui.mn/azhild-avna/mt-hariltsaa-holboo/slzhee-tehnik-hangamzh/ulan-bator/

**Code Snippet:**

```
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    cards = response.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'announcement-container')]")
    # parse details
    for card in cards: 
    company = card.xpath(".//*[@class='announcement-block__company-name']/text()").extract_first()
    date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first().split(',')
    date = date_block[0]
    city = date_block[1]

    item = {'date': date,
           'city': city,
           'company': company
           }
```

**HTML Snippet:**

```html
<div class="announcement-block__date">
<span class="announcement-block__company-name">Электро экспресс ХХК</span>
,          Өчигдөр 13:05,                  Улаанбаатар</div>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
date = Өчигдөр 13:05
city = Улаанбаатар
```

**UPDATE:** I figured out how to get my date and city data. I ended up using follow next sibling to get date, split by comma, and get the 2nd and 3rd values.

```
    date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/span/following-sibling::text())").extract_first().split(',')
    date = date_block[1]
    city = date_block[2]
```

**Extra:**

If anyone can tell me or refer me to how I can setup my pipeline file would be greatly appreciated. Is it correct to use pipeline or should you use items.py? Currently I have 3 spiders in the same project folder: apartments, jobs, cars. I need to clean my data and transform it. For example, for the jobs spider I am currently working on as shown above I want to create the following manipulations:

- if salary is < 1000, then replace with string 'Negotiable'
- if date contains the text "Өчигдөр" then replace with 'Yesterday'
  without deleting the time
- if employer contains value 'Хувь хүн' then change company value to 'Хувь хүн'

my pipelines.py file:

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter


class ScrapebooksPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

my items.py file:

```
import scrapy


class ScrapebooksItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Comment: Can you share a link of that web page?

Comment: https://www.unegui.mn/azhild-avna/mt-hariltsaa-holboo/slzhee-tehnik-hangamzh/ulan-bator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I changed your xpath to a smaller scope.
2. extract_first() will get the first instance, so use getall() instead.
3. In order to get the date I had to use regex (most of the results have time but not date so if you get a blank for the date it's perfectly fine).
4. I can't read the language so I had to guess (kind of) for the city, but even if it's wrong you can get the point.

```py
import scrapy
import re


class TempSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'temp_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['unegui.mn']
    start_urls = ['https://www.unegui.mn/azhild-avna/ulan-bator/']

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        cards = response.xpath('//div[@class="announcement-block__date"]')

        # parse details
        for card in cards:
            company = card.xpath('.//span/text()').get()

            date_block = card.xpath('./text()').getall()

            date = date_block[1].strip()
            date = re.findall(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+)', date)
            if date:
                date = date[0]
            else:
                date = ''

            city = date_block[1].split(',')[2].strip()

            item = {'date': date,
                    'city': city,
                    'company': company
                    }
            yield item
```

Output:

```py
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.unegui.mn/azhild-avna/ulan-bator/>
{'date': '2021-11-07', 'city': 'Улаанбаатар', 'company': 'Arirang'}
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.unegui.mn/azhild-avna/ulan-bator/>
{'date': '2021-11-11', 'city': 'Улаанбаатар', 'company': 'Altangadas'}
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.unegui.mn/azhild-avna/ulan-bator/>
...
...
...
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your input. I added your code and tried running and got city = date_block[1].split(',')[2].strip() ---- list index out of range. One question I had was is there a performance impact on having longer xpaths or having smaller ones like yours? Especially when paginating. Each spider I created needs to go through around 80-120 pages (4000-6000 listings). I added my full code into my original post just in case.

Comment: Additionally, the reason why some dates are missing is because Өнөөдөр = Today, Өчигдөр = Yesterday, I need to get these 2 values as well so I can convert them to the scrapped day's date, or previous date.

Comment: I ended up getting the date and city. Do you know how I can transform item values using if statements? Should I put it in the pipelines.py file or items.py file? How should I structure it if you have any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by `transform item values`?

Comment: As in manipulate the scraped data values (i.e. clean the data and add/remove sections). For example, replace certain string values with another, or if one value = x, then another value will be =y, else it will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing indentation.
Instead

```py
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    cards = response.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'announcement-container')]")
    # parse details
    for card in cards: date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first().split(',')
    date = date_block[0]
    city = date_block[1]
```

Try this:

```py
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    cards = response.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'announcement-container')]")
    # parse details
    for card in cards: date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first().split(',')
        date = date_block[0]
        city = date_block[1]
```

Comment: Hi. It seems I missed a space while formatting my code on stackoverflow. I apologize. I edited it. I added a bit more code so it may be more clearer. When I indent as shown by you, I get an error and it wont run.